# Linear convergence rate

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I have a non-negative sequence $\alpha_k$ such that
$$ 0 < \alpha_{k+1} \leq \left(\frac{1}{1+a}\right)^{k+1} \alpha_{0} + \sum_{j=0}^{k}{\left(\frac{1}{1+a}\right)^{k-j+1} \beta_j^2}$$
where $a >0$ and the sequence $\{\beta_j\}$ is a non-negative non-increasing sequence such that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \beta_j^2 < \infty$. In the abscense of the second term on the right hand side, I would have been able to conclude that $\{\alpha_k\}$ has a linear convergence rate, but with its presence, not sure if I can still say something about the convergence of the sequence or its rate if it is convergent. I can impose additional assumptions on the sequence $\{\beta_k\}$ if needed.

Comment: Why should the sequence $\alpha$ converge? The best you can hope from the RHS is that the sequence is bounded. And actually without any hypothesis on the non-negativity of $\alpha$, even without the term in $\beta$ the sequence $\alpha$ may diverge to $-\infty$.

Comment: @ECL: the sequence $\alpha$ is actually non-negative. I edited the post.

Comment: Still, if $\beta$ is not trivially $0$ the best you can hope for is something like $\alpha_{k}\leq b^k \alpha_0 + C$ for $b = 1/(1+a)$ and $C>0$ (and hopefully $C<\infty$), which does not even mean that $\alpha$ converge since for $k\to\infty$ it just reduces to $\alpha_k\leq C$.

Comment: @ECL: based on your derivation, I can write $\alpha_k \leq b^k \left(\alpha_0 + \sum_{j=0}^k  (1+a)^j (\beta_j)^2 \right)$, so if I show that the sum term is finite as $k \rightarrow \infty$, that would mean that the sequence is convergent, right? but does that give an idea of its rate of convergence?

Comment: $$ 0 < \alpha_{k+1} \leq \left(\frac{1}{1+a}\right)^{k+1} \alpha_{0} + \sum_{j=0}^{k}{\left(\frac{1}{1+a}\right)^{k-j+1} \beta_j^2} = \left(\frac{1}{1+a}\right)^{k+1}\left(\alpha_0 + \sum\limits_{j=0}^k(1+a)^j\beta_j^2\right)\\
\leq\left(\frac{1}{1+a}\right)^{k+1}\left(\alpha_0 + \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty(1+a)^j\beta_j^2\right)$$

So one thing you could ask is that $\{(1+a)^j\beta_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^1$. This would imply that $\alpha_k\to 0$.

Comment: @TSF: In the case, the convergence rate is linear, right?

Comment: Yes, let $b=1/1+a \in ]0,1[$ and $C = \alpha_0 + \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty (1+a)^j\beta_j^2$. We would have $\alpha_k\leq b^kC$. By the way, I made a mistake writing my previous comment. You need $(1+a)^j\beta_j^2$ to be summable, I forgot to square $\beta_j$.